# How to make a dataframe calculating bounded mean and identifying its number of data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I have this dataset:

```
Data <- tribble(~Name,  ~Age,   ~Gender,
             "Cristian",    74, "Male",
             "Ana", 19, "Female",
             "Luis",    20, "Male",
             "Jaime",   21, "Male",
             "Jennifer",    18, "Female")
```

Making a data frame calculating for age variable I get this outcome:

| Gender | AgeMean | Total | Trimmed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Female | 18.5 | 2 | 0 |
| Male | 38.3 | 3 | 0 |

But I would want to calculate a bounded mean for age variable at 40% and my expected outcome would be this:

| Gender | AgeMean | Total | Trimmed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Female | 18.5 | 2 | 0.4 |
| Male | 21 | 2 | 0.4 |

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much for your help.

Greetings!

Comment: How do you get the final `Total` value?

Answer (score 0):

The `mean` also have a `trim` argument.  We can use that to get the bounded mean, along with 'Total' calculated based on the same formula used in `mean.default` for `trim`ming

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(Gender) %>%
  mutate(lo = floor(n() * 0.4) + 1) %>%
  summarise(AgeMean = mean(Age, trim = 0.4),
     Total = length(first(lo):(n() + 1 - first(lo))),
    Trimmed = 0.4, .groups = 'drop')
```